# Quick search in table

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have a problem.

I want to make a qiuck search box in html table genrated by php array.

My table code :

```
 <table class="demo">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><input type="checkbox" class="check_all" ></th>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>DB</th>
                    <th>Name</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($this->data as $key => $value_db) { ?>                   
                    <tr>
                        <td class="center"><input type="checkbox" value="<?= $value_db['id']; ?>" title="test_<?= $value_db['db']; ?>"></td>
                        <td class="center"><?= $value_db['id']; ?></td>
                        <td class="center">name_<?= $value_db['db']; ?></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
    </table>
```

And i dont know to do the uick box search. I dont wannt search results pagination, all i want is the quick search in DB names.

I try to do this

```
<script>
        function SrchSubmit() 
        {
                var valu= document.getElementById("valu").value;
                url="mydommain?a=s&query={0.CT." + valu + "}";
                location.href = url;
        }
</script>
 <form>
    <input id="valu" style="margin-right: 15px;"/>
    </form>

    <input type="button" value="Search" onClick="SrchSubmit()" style="width:135px;font: bold 12px Arial;">
```

But it didnt work, and i dont want search results in different window. How to make a quick search box (in html, pp or jQ) ?

Comment: What happens when you clcik on the search button?

Comment: Nothing, i got error in console.

Comment: Please paste the error here.